# Python Executor - Passing function with argument as argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, encapsulation, concurrent.futures

My goal is to create a function that I can use to measure the execution and resource use of another function. Using a tutorial, I've create the below using Python's ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
from resource import *
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

class MemoryMonitor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.keep_measuring = True

    def measure_usage(self):
        max_usage = 0
        u_run_time = 0
        s_run_time = 0
        while self.keep_measuring:
            max_usage = max(max_usage, getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)
            u_run_time = max(u_run_time, getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF).ru_utime) 
            s_run_time = max(s_run_time, getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF).ru_stime) 
        sleep(0.1) # run this loop every 0.1 seconds
        return [max_usage, u_run_time, s_run_time]

def execute(function):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        monitor = MemoryMonitor()
        stats_thread = executor.submit(monitor.measure_usage)
        try:
            fn_thread = executor.submit(function)
            result = fn_thread.result()
            print("print result")
            print(result)
            print("print result type")
            print(type(result))
        finally:
            monitor.keep_measuring = False
            stats = stats_thread.result()
        print(stats)
        return result

def foo():
    i = 0
    while i < 3:
        print("foo")
        i+=1
    return 1

def bar(x):
    while x < 3:
        print("foobar")
        x+=1
    return 1

var = execute(foo)
print("Var = " + str(var))
var = execute(bar(0))
print("Var = " + str(var))
```

If I pass the function *foo* as an argument to the function *execute*, it prints the correct results and returns the value returned by foo.

If I pass the function *bar* in the same way, but with bar itself requiring an argument, the function runs (prints 3 times) and then I get the following error:

```
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

After some testing, the part where I'm stuck appears to be passing a function as an argument, if that function itself requires an argument. As I understand the ThreadPoolExecutor, the *fn_thread* object encapsulates the execution of the function submitted. The *result* object should simply hold the result of that execution - what am I missing that this cannot handle being passed a function with an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are submitting

```
bar(0)
```

instead of

```
bar, 0
```

To clarify, look at the submit's signature:
submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)

the result of

```
bar(0)
```

is an integer, and the executor cannot call an integer, since it is not 'callable', as the error message suggests.

Comment: There it is - thank you! I guess the answer here is to overload the execute function so that it can accept calls in both cases. For future reference of anyone looking at this, overloading to def execute(function, args=None) and adjusting the fn_thread call to fit both options was the correct path.

Comment: You're welcome! It should also work if you put 
```
def execute(function, *args):
   ...
```
as your definition.